# How do you retrieve HTML from an external website into a variable in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

In PHP there's a simple function called `file_get_contents`, and if I wanted to retrieve and display the HTML on, say, google.com, I would just do this:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $html;
?>
```

Is there an equivalent to this in ColdFusion? Can you retrieve the output of an external site into a string variable (and then manipulate it accordingly)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest cross-engine equivalent of what you've written is:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.google.com/" />
<cfset html = cfhttp.FileContent />
<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>
```

You can specify an alternative to the auto-created cfhttp variable like this:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.google.com/" result="Response" />
<cfset html = Response.FileContent />
<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>
```

Both of those will work in all major CFML engines ([Adobe CF](http://adobe.com/coldfusion), [OpenBD](http://www.openbluedragon.org), [Railo](http://www.getrailo.org)).

You can see the full set of options (methods,params,proxy settings,etc) in the [cfhttp documentation](http://cfdocs.org/cfhttp), and to see the full response struct, just use `<cfdump var=#cfhttp#/>` after a call (or whatever the result var is named).

There is an extra option which works with Railo, which is more directly what you've got in PHP, Like this:

```
<cfset html = FileRead('http://www.google.com/') />
<cfoutput>#html#</cfoutput>
```

This works because Railo has Resources (virtual filesystems), so everywhere you can do a file operation, you can use various virtual filesystems, including HTTP, ZIP, RAM, and others.

(Adobe have started adding virtual filesystems also, but I think so far only support RAM, so this doesn't work there.)

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfset destination = "http://www.google.com">
<cfhttp url = #destination# method = "post" result="httpResult">
<cfoutput>#httpResult.fileContent#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfhttp method="Get"
   url="127.0.0.1/blah.html"
   name="myvar">
 <cfdump var="#myvar#">
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The `name` attribute is for the name of a query variable, when converting the URL from CSV->query object.